# Error in passing Second condition in where clause in sqoop import partial table

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import a partial table from MySQL to HDFS database. I tried Sqoop import. It is working when I am applying only one condition in where clause.
 But when I add one more condition it gives me error:

```
Error parsing arguments for import:
```

Query is following:

`sqoop import --table accounts --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --username myuser --password mypw --target-dir /homeworks/sqoop/ --where "state='CA'" and "acct_close_dt IS NULL"`

Comment: see title 7.2.3. Free-form Query Imports, this will help https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with **Free-form Query Imports**:

`sqoop import --table accounts --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --username myuser --password mypw --target-dir /homeworks/sqoop/ --query "select * from accounts where state='CA' and acct_close_dt IS NULL AND \$CONDITIONS"`

If you are writing `--query` in single quotes(') use `$CONDITIONS` instead of `\$CONDITIONS`

Check [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html) as suggested by Piyush.